# Salesforce SDK error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content has been consumed

Tags: apex

I have developed a android application using the Salesforce SDK. I am facing an odd issue, when the same user or different user logs on 3 to 4 times then logs out of application immediately.

I would then get “java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content has been consumed” error thrown by the volly.jar library. Can any one help me with this issue? Here is the detailed log for reference:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content has been consumed
>   12-17 15:28:53.630: E/Volley(22192):    at org.apache.http.entity.BasicHttpEntity.getContent(BasicHttpEntity.java:84)
>   12-17 15:28:53.630: E/Volley(22192):    at org.apache.http.conn.BasicManagedEntity.getContent(BasicManagedEntity.java:100)
>   12-17 15:28:53.630: E/Volley(22192):    at android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient.getUngzippedContent(AndroidHttpClient.java:229)
>   12-17 15:28:53.630: E/Volley(22192):    at com.salesforce.androidsdk.auth.HttpAccess$GzipDecompressingEntity.getContent(HttpAccess.java:447)
>   12-17 15:28:53.630: E/Volley(22192):    at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.entityToBytes(BasicNetwork.java:215)
>   12-17 15:28:53.630: E/Volley(22192):    at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:107)
>   12-17 15:28:53.630: E/Volley(22192):    at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:110)
>   12-17 15:28:53.686: W/System.err(22192): java.lang.NullPointerException

I get this error when I tried to read the user’s first name using below query:

> String smartSqlQuery = "Select Id,Name From User where Id = '" + userId + "'";
>   sendRequest(smartSqlQuery, USER);

```
private void sendRequest(String soql, final String obj) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{

    final RestRequest restRequest = RestRequest.getRequestForQuery(getString(R.string.api_version), soql);
    HoughtonApplication.client.sendAsync(restRequest, new AsyncRequestCallback()
    {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(RestRequest request, RestResponse result)
        {
            try
            {
                final JSONArray records = result.asJSONObject().getJSONArray(RECORDS);
                Log.e("==== User Records",":: "+records.toString());
                if (obj.equals(USER))
                {
                    if (records.length() != 0)
                        Log.e("==== User Records",":: "+ records.getJSONObject(0).optString(NAME));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                onError(e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```